# Making a 4 blocks layout (2 superimposed)

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like to a 4 blocks layout like this:

[image]

I've been trying things with float but I really don't master it.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

My HTML code:

```
<div id="colonne_gauche">1</div>

<div id="colonne_gauche2">2</div>

<div id="colonne_droite">4</div>

<div id="colonne_centre">3</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
#colonne_gauche
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    -float: left;
    width: 420px;
    height: 145px;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    background: red;
}

#colonne_gauche2
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 420px;
    height: 145px;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    background: orange;
}

#colonne_centre
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 295px;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    background: green;
}

#colonne_droite
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 295px;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    background: blue;
}
```

I just played a little with the floating and see what that does.

Comment: This question is too broad in my opinion. I wouldn't be surprised if it will b e closed. It would be better and you have a higher chance of getting a useful answer if you provided some code that demonstrates how far you have got.

Comment: Well, I'm very new to css/html and I have no idea how to do that. This is the best I could come up with:

http://s8.postimg.org/q2sx5rg85/layout.png

Comment: @Tommyisk4 Make sure you understand basic CSS properties like `float` before continuing. Getting the answer here will only help you in the short run and you're gonna end up with a lot of headaches when working with layout if you lack the CSS basis. The good thing is there's plenty of resources for learning CSS online. This is my recommendation for beginners: [http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web)

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS which you've written so far.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading lots of content and watching lots of tutos. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gLxj8yjm/5/).

HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="stackleft">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
</div>
<div id="stackright">
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 960px;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#one {
    width: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 145px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
#two {
    width: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 145px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
#three {
    width: 310px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 295px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#four {
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 295px;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#stackleft, #stackright {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xam558e3/

Using DIV's inside of other DIV's you can easily control how they appear, and where they appear.  You should look up the box model, it may shed some light for you on this.

```
<div style="width:310px">
    <div style="width:303px; height: 100px; background-color: #6495ed;"></div>
    <div style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;  float:left; margin: 1px;"></div>
    <div style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;  float:left; margin: 1px;"></div>
    <div style="width:100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;  float:left; margin: 1px;"></div>
    <div style="width:303px; height: 100px; background-color: red; float:left; margin: 1px;"></div>
</div>
```